# Virus Issue for my websites

Tags: php, html, security, virus

This is the serious issue, I found HTML/PHP file on my FTP server uploaded by someone else. I have used strong password, but someone trying to hack my server. this happened twice with me.

The HTML/PHP page is containing code which written "your website is hacked!" and this page is uploaded in each and every folder of my server. I have removed these files and uploaded my backups, but do we have any security code, which do not allow anyone to inject files on FTP, or any security tips for FTP?

Here I am writing the HTML page code, which file has been uploaded to my Folders.

I need help for my security reasons.

Note : Please copy this code and run on your local browser, so you can get idea.

Thanks and regards,
Vrnda

```html
<!--    







                     ,        ,

                  /(        )`

                  \ \___   / |

              /- _  `-/  '

               (/\/ \ \   /\

               / /   | `    \

               O O   ) /    |

               `-^--'`<     '

              (_.)  _  )   /

               `.___/`    /

               `-----' /

        <----.     __ / __   \

        <----|====O)))==) \) /====

        <----'    `--' `.__,' \

               |        |

                \       /

            ______( (_  / \______

            ,'  ,-----'   |        \

            `--{__________)        \/





  root@0xaN0n:~# bash 0xaN0n.sh

  ~ <start>

  ~ Script by 0xaN0n | Garooda Security Squad

  ~ Mau copy?? Silahkan

  ~ Keep Support My Team [ Garooda Security Squad ]

  ~ https://www.facebook.com/groosec.go.id

  ~ https://0xaN0n.xyz

  ~ </start>

  root@0xaN0n:~# poweroff























  

-->



<html>

  <head>

    <title>Hacked by OTnaytrue</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Keania+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" href="https://s28.postimg.org/n5r1hjerh/bqc_LRGO2.png" />

    <meta property="og:image" content="https://s28.postimg.org/n5r1hjerh/bqc_LRGO2.png">

    <meta content="OTnaytrue - Garooda Security Squad" name="description">

    <meta content="Hacked by OTnaytrue" name="keywords">

    <meta content="Hacked by OTnaytrue" name="keywords">

    <meta content="Hacked by OTnaytrue" name="Abstract">

    <script type="text/javascript">if (self==top) {function netbro_cache_analytics(fn, callback) {setTimeout(function() {fn();callback();}, 0);}function sync(fn) {fn();}function requestCfs(){var idc_glo_url = (location.protocol=="https:" ? "https://" : "http://");var idc_glo_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);var url = idc_glo_url+ "cfs2.uzone.id/2fn7a2/request" + "?id=1" + "&enc=9UwkxLgY9" + "&params=" + "4TtHaUQnUEiP6K%2fc5C582CL4NjpNgssKx%2fk%2f%2bUw0t0AH4no8FuNqZi9RYWWBQyQp0AHtS9VsumAX9UXmINwfamqfP%2bhBuKGBLUUYXicYjmM20YkqOwAdJtoE%2fcxyntKQyuef78x7ZyAufxf%2fOkm1Nd3J2AxD9NEpk%2bXHNkloX0VkcwNaQ3ob4ZiJdmouDyU0sPSjmnvjqC%2fKckHNj8n6eLy8IIIVVeZXvb9KSn%2blQdIwYra1LYGL3IeADYmd8A6Q7EDHQ5lXiiLjAJuuLlEYYgFWO4ePcQ0TONWgJAScS9jrRfCZp%2fIVRH7RzQb8zAZEjZjbRCnga%2fLZ2HDdgcWuhcFI5cpV5ya53ff3ebBBcFkk%2f7h46AW4Off4As9mJM0MAl%2fSFvgoxqQoipHdYLYkpq9aFVfDYpVd0bW4mG6VNsY5SgpLmsjOiG6syXGwKB5%2fTc%2fccCsvKOO%2fpZSnsyMYPXR6WiPVVebQs74v%2bC2UeVksLsErNCjJYCG7z362eknVYD9bhf5f4jFsgK4R79KrZs4PU%2fmgH5LB8%2fDLm9WMHHTUx6fSsJiNN4elM1ApjnAi" + "&idc_r="+idc_glo_r + "&domain="+document.domain + "&sw="+screen.width+"&sh="+screen.height;var bsa = document.createElement('script');bsa.type = 'text/javascript';bsa.async = true;bsa.src = url;(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa);}netbro_cache_analytics(requestCfs, function(){});};</script></body>

    <style>

      body {

        background: transparent;

        background: url(https://s23.postimg.org/za9vse2mj/IMG-20170525-_WA0009.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

        background-attachment: fixed;

        background-position: 50%;

        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        background-size: cover;

        text-shadow: grey 0px 0px 10px;

        height : auto;

        width : 100%;

        }

      

      #kiri {

        position: fixed;

        width: auto;

        left : 30px;

        text-shadow: grey 0px 0px 10px;

        text-decoration: none;

        }

      #kanan {

        position: fixed;

        float : right;

        margin: 0 40px 40px 530px;

        text-shadow: grey 0px 0px 10px;

        }

      .button {

         margin-top:50px; 

         padding:10px; 

         background-color:red; 

         color:#FFF;

         text-decoration: none;

         }

      .ntot {

        font size:8px;

        text-align: center;

        font-family: Pirata One;

        font-family: Keania One;

        text-shadow: 4px 4px 50px #000000;

        }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="particles-js">

    <center>

      <div id=bar style="position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0px; font-family: Tahoma; height: 20px; color: white; font-size: 13px; left: 0px; border-bottom: 2px solid darkred; padding: 0px; background-color: #000">

        <b>

        

          Garooda Security Squad - Eotnay@gmail.com

          

        </b>  

      </div>

      <br>

    </center>

    <div class="ntot">

    

      <br><br><br><br><br>

    

    <div id="kiri">

      <center>

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groosec.go.id"><img border="0" alt="0xaN0n" src="https://s28.postimg.org/n5r1hjerh/bqc_LRGO2.png" width="400" height="300"></a>

          <br><br><br><br>

        <a class="button" target="_blank" href="mailto:eotnay@gmail.com">Contact Me</a>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;

        <a class="button" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/groosec.go.id">  Find Me  </a>

      </center>

    </div>

    <div id="kanan">

      <br><br>

      <center>

        <font size="8" color="red">

        

        "Be Secure SIR "

        

      <br><br>

        <font size="6" color="white">

            

          OTnaytrue<font color="grey"> ft</font> Civilian 

            

        </font>

      <br>

        <font size="6" color="grey">

            

        [ Garooda Security Squad ]

            

      <br><br>

            

          .: We Are :.

            

        </font>

      <br>

        <font size="5" color="red">

            

          _MisterNotFound_ | 0xaN0n | PandaKecil | Mr.R007 | Mr.Z_4202 | cyber_xr00t | <font color="grey">Civilian </font>|

          Mr.404 |  Mr.RequestTimeOut | Dull_1999 | D!@m@nt3 | ins7ing | SyntaX404 | Mr.DarkNight |

          Rabbids404 | Mr.PHP404ERROR | <font color="grey">OTnaytrue</font> | AFK404 | MKNotfound477 | ./St4rXr4tS | GunshootCbr | HeartBeat

            

        </font>

      </center>

    </div>

    

    <DIV style="DISPLAY: none">

      <AUDIO controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">

        <SOURCE type="audio/mpeg" src="http://www.topas-tv.com/config/skillet.mp3">

      </AUDIO>

    </DIV>

    </div>

    <script src="https://0xan0n.xyz/non/js/particles.js"></script>

    <script src="https://0xan0n.xyz/non/js/app.js"></script>

  </body>

  <footer>

    <center>

      <div id=bar style="position: fixed; width: 100%; bottom: 0px; font-family: Tahoma; height: 20px; color: white; font-size: 13px; left: 0px; border-top: 2px solid darkred; padding: 0px; background-color: #000">

        <b>

          

          Greetz : [ <marquee behavior="alternate" width="59%"><font color="red">Kakatoji  - ./bl4ckj4ck - Gadjah Mada - PURPLESM0KE - BerdendangC0de - 0xd3vs - IndoXploit  - Kedaong Crew -  TKJ Cyber Art  - Clown Hacktivism Team - Indonesia Defacer Tersakiti Team  -  Bima Cyber Team  -  T1KUS90T  -  IDCA - Garuda Security Hacker - And All Indonesian Defacer</font></marquee>]

          

        </b>

      </div>

    </center>

    </div>

  </footer>

    <!--[0xTrueCode-Brown anti copass Click kanan :V]--!>

 <script language=JavaScript>

var message="Ooops.. OTnaytrue Was Here";



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function clickIE4(){

if (event.button==2){

alert(message);

return false;

}

}



function clickNS4(e){

if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){

if (e.which==2||e.which==3){

alert(message);

return false;

}

}

}



if (document.layers){

document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);

document.onmousedown=clickNS4;

}

else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){

document.onmousedown=clickIE4;

}



document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")

</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

//<![CDATA[

shortcut={all_shortcuts:{},add:function(a,b,c){var d={type:"keydown",propagate:!1,disable_in_input:!1,target:document,keycode:!1};if(c)for(var e in d)"undefined"==typeof c[e]&&(c[e]=d[e]);else c=d;d=c.target,"string"==typeof c.target&&(d=document.getElementById(c.target)),a=a.toLowerCase(),e=function(d){d=d||window.event;if(c.disable_in_input){var e;d.target?e=d.target:d.srcElement&&(e=d.srcElement),3==e.nodeType&&(e=e.parentNode);if("INPUT"==e.tagName||"TEXTAREA"==e.tagName)return}d.keyCode?code=d.keyCode:d.which&&(code=d.which),e=String.fromCharCode(code).toLowerCase(),188==code&&(e=","),190==code&&(e=".");var f=a.split("+"),g=0,h={"`":"~",1:"!",2:"@",3:"#",4:"$",5:"%",6:"^",7:"&",8:"*",9:"(",0:")","-":"_","=":"+",";":":","'":'"',",":"<",".":">","/":"?","\\":"|"},i={esc:27,escape:27,tab:9,space:32,"return":13,enter:13,backspace:8,scrolllock:145,scroll_lock:145,scroll:145,capslock:20,caps_lock:20,caps:20,numlock:144,num_lock:144,num:144,pause:19,"break":19,insert:45,home:36,"delete":46,end:35,pageup:33,page_up:33,pu:33,pagedown:34,page_down:34,pd:34,left:37,up:38,right:39,down:40,f1:112,f2:113,f3:114,f4:115,f5:116,f6:117,f7:118,f8:119,f9:120,f10:121,f11:122,f12:123},j=!1,l=!1,m=!1,n=!1,o=!1,p=!1,q=!1,r=!1;d.ctrlKey&&(n=!0),d.shiftKey&&(l=!0),d.altKey&&(p=!0),d.metaKey&&(r=!0);for(var s=0;k=f[s],s<f.length;s++)"ctrl"==k||"control"==k?(g++,m=!0):"shift"==k?(g++,j=!0):"alt"==k?(g++,o=!0):"meta"==k?(g++,q=!0):1<k.length?i[k]==code&&g++:c.keycode?c.keycode==code&&g++:e==k?g++:h[e]&&d.shiftKey&&(e=h[e],e==k&&g++);if(g==f.length&&n==m&&l==j&&p==o&&r==q&&(b(d),!c.propagate))return d.cancelBubble=!0,d.returnValue=!1,d.stopPropagation&&(d.stopPropagation(),d.preventDefault()),!1},this.all_shortcuts[a]={callback:e,target:d,event:c.type},d.addEventListener?d.addEventListener(c.type,e,!1):d.attachEvent?d.attachEvent("on"+c.type,e):d["on"+c.type]=e},remove:function(a){var a=a.toLowerCase(),b=this.all_shortcuts[a];delete this.all_shortcuts[a];if(b){var a=b.event,c=b.target,b=b.callback;c.detachEvent?c.detachEvent("on"+a,b):c.removeEventListener?c.removeEventListener(a,b,!1):c["on"+a]=!1}}},shortcut.add("Ctrl+U",function(){top.location.href="https://web.facebook.com/OTnaytrue"});

//]]>

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Contact your hosting provider - They must solve this issue. Also, this question, in my opinion, should be moved to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: The PHP part of your website probably has a vulnerability. Impossible to say where without more information.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use FTP but rather SFTP or at least FTPS. Using FTP, your login and password are transmitted in plain text over the network, for everyone to see. I believe your provider must be offering either one of the options above, if not please move your site elsewhere.

Remove any existing access and create a new one, with a strong password. If you can, try ssh authentication using public/private key rather than password.

On your hosting account, chances are you can set a 2 factors authentication. If you can please do.

Then, in terms of code, look for the keywords `eval`,`file_put_contents`, `fputs` and so on.